# android public method setItemIconTintList() in BottomNavigationView is not available (android studio 4.1, Kotlin)

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, bottomnavigationview, android-bottomnav

I am trying to set the BottomNavigation Icon tint to null

I am using Android Studio 4.1 and Kotlin as my language and created the bottom navigation from the android create project

`val navView: BottomNavigationView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view)`

But when i try to declare null to setItemIconTintList() its not available

[image]

I am new to this please help me out how to set the tint to null

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have it highlighted in the screenshot:

`itemIconTintList`

set it by:

`navView.itemIconTintList = null`